# handle decrement going into negative values

Tags: reactjs

Created a method of handle increment and I have set

```
this.setState(oldState => ( {counters:( oldState.counters > 0) ? (oldState.counters - 1) : 0 } ))
```

When I clicked on handle decrement button, I get this error

> TypeError: this.state.counters.reduce is not a function

[image]

For stopping from negative value I used

this.setState(oldState => ( {counters:( oldState.counters > 0) ? (oldState.counters - 1) : 0 } ))

When I liked on button, I now get this error:

[image]

Counter is a component in which i placed a decrement button in its I want that if the value is zero it will stop going to negative values

Here is my code

```
class Counters extends Component {
    state = {
        counters:[
            {id:1, value:0},
            {id:2, value:0},
            {id:3, value:0},
            {id:4, value:0}
        ]
    }
    
    handleIncrement = counter => {
        const counters = [...this.state.counters];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
        counters[index] = {...counter}
        counters[index].value++;
        this.setState({counters})
    }
    
    handleDecrement=counter=>{
        const counters = [...this.state.counters];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
        counters[index] = {...counter}
        counters[index].value--;
        this.setState({counters})
        this.setState(oldState => (
            { counters: (oldState.counters > 0) ? (oldState.counters - 1) : 0 }
        ))
    }
    
    handleDelete= (counterid) => {
      const counters = this.state.counters.filter(m => m.id !== counterid)
      this.setState({counters})
    }
    
    handleReset=()=>{
        const counters = this.state.counters.map(m => { 
            m.value = 0;
             return m
        })
        
        this.setState({counters})
    }
        
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.counters.reduce((a,b)=>({value:a.value+b.value})).value}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.handleReset} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">RESET</button>
                {
                    this.state.counters.map(m =>
                        <Counter key={m.id} 
                            id={m.id} getDelete={this.handleDelete}
                            onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
                            onDecrement={this.handleDecrement}
                            counter={m} />) 
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
    
export default Counters;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the solution. Simply change your `handleDecrement` to this

```
    handleDecrement=counter=>{
        const counters =[...this.state.counters];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
        counters[index]={...counter};
        counters[index].value = counters[index].value > 0 ? (counters[index].value - 1) : 0;
        this.setState({counters});
    }
```

The reason why you were encountering the error is because of this line in `handleDecrement`

```
 this.setState(oldState => (
    {counters:( oldState.counters > 0) ? (oldState.counters - 1) : 0 }
 ))
```

This line changes `counters` in the state to a number, and a number does not have the `.reduce` function.

Some additional feedback:

- the design of the `Counters` class is a little weird. You should consider shifting the increment/decrement logic into the `Counter` class instead so each `Counter` would manage its own count.
- you should never have consecutive `.setState` calls like you did in your `handleDecrement` function. `.setState` is async, meaning there is no guarantee that the order of execution will be preserved. Either combine the two calls into one or use the `.then` function of setState to chain them together.